# When to use OBO with Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to develop a SaaS application on Azure and deploy to the Azure marketplace. This app will be able to obtain information about the user's network. (for instance VNET information). Ideally I would like to have a single-page application that would authenticate with the user who subscribed to the app, and then make calls on a backend API tier, which would make calls to Azure management API endpoints.

The Azure docs layout a number of scenarios of how apps could interface with AD. [how-to guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/)

I believe what im trying to do most closely matches the "Build a web app that calls web APIs" flow, which is an example of OBO.  My question is, is that really describing what im doing? Is "calls web APIs" really an example of invoking APIs on the microsoft azure platform?

So my understanding is that I would develop my own API app, that would accept requests from my client browser code, which would contain an oauth token, and then the API layer would derive another token to pass onto the Azure API layer?

Im trying to keep the architecture as simple as possible, but im afraid I may be misinterpreting the Azure docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OBO (On-Behalf-Of) allows you to exchange an access token that your API received for an access token to another API.
The important bit is that the access token must have been acquired in the context of the user and must contain user information.
The new access token will then also contain this user's info.

So it allows your back-end API to call Azure Management APIs *on behalf of* the current user.
This means your API can't do anything the current user can't do.
It is limited to the user's own access rights.

The other option for authentication is to use client credentials authentication,
where your back-end API uses only a client id + certificate/secret to authenticate.
In this case the token will not contain user information.
To enable this approach, the target organization's users would have to assign RBAC access rights to your app's service principal, so it can act by itself.
You could also build a flow in your app where you setup these RBAC accesses on behalf of the current user.

Personally, I would prefer to use delegated access (OBO) whenever possible, as it will block the user from doing things they cannot do.
Though on the other hand, service principal-based access allows the organization to control your app's access better.

Comment: Juunas I think you really crystalized OBO for me, just by your first sentence. So you're saying that if I had my own API, with my own proprietary oauth scheme, I would use OBO to integrate with a completely different AD or idp. In my case, im considering using angular for my UI, and I would have a SaaS layer API. The user would subscribe to this app from the marketplace. And would thus grant the app access to make api calls with their access token. I don't believe the OBO is warranted in this case, because the only access token involved is the one from Microsoft. Am I understanding properly?

Comment: OBO can only be used if your API also uses OAuth with Azure AD. Not your own proprietary provider.