# Consent is not showing in Microsoft Identity auth with api://{BackendClientId}/.default scope

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying to configure WASM Blazor client with WebAPI server to use Microsoft identity authentication. I dug deep, followed many advice from StackOverflow (thanks for them) and these are the steps I have used for configuration:

Configured a pair of app registrations in Azure:

[image]

Configured delegated permissions in the backend registration:

[image]

Configured and exposed API scope:

[image]

Configured knownClientApplications to point to frontend registration:

[image]

Configured permissions in the frontend registration:

[image]

I am using Blazor WASM as the client - The configuration of the authentication client is as follows:

[image]

When I run the authentication, the proper token is issued (I have checked the content). The problem is, that the consent screen (with backend consents) is not presented to the user. Consents are not there (OBO flow fails with the backend not having consent) - I have also checked in the portal - no consents are there.

Does anyhow have any idea, why the consent screen is not showing? Is there something more I have to do?

Thank you very much.

1. I have tried different scopes - ".default" - proper consent screen is presented, the token is issued for incorrect scopes (MS Graph ones)
2. The auth itself is configured properly - when the consent is there, everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that: The on behalf of (OBO) flow defines the situation where a web API calls another web API using an identity other than its own.

Based on your configuration, the frontend application calls the backend Api and using the access token generated it calls the Microsoft Graph API using OBO flow.

I created an **Azure AD Backend Application** and added API permissions:

[image]

Now, I created **Azure AD Frontend Application** and added permissions:

[image]

To authorize users, I used below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://BackendAppID/.default
&state=12345
```

Frontend consent:

[image]

Backend Consent:

[image]

**Auth-code** got generated successfully:

[image]

By using the **Frontend Application**, I tried to call backend web Api via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:FrontendAppID
scope:api://BackendAppID/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the token **aud** is web Api:

[image]

Now by passing the above generated access token, **I called Microsoft Graph API** using OBO flow:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion:access_token
requested_token_use:on_behalf_of
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, **aud** is Microsoft Graph:

[image]

By using the above token, you can call Microsoft Graph API.

- If you want to call only the web Api (`api://ClientID/.default`) then you can implement Authorization code flow instead of OBO flow.
- Refer this [**blog**](https://dev.to/425show/just-what-is-the-default-scope-in-the-microsoft-identity-platform-azure-ad-2o4d) to know more about the consents by John Patrick Dandison.
- The Backend API doesn't ask consent for API as the web Api is not added in the API permissions.

**References:**

[Microsoft identity platform and OAuth2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)

[When to use OBO with Azure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59513343/when-to-use-obo-with-azure)  by Junnas

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. Information you have provided was extremely helpful. In addition to your guide, it was necessary to add knownClientApplications to the manifest (otherwise consent asked is incomplete - User.ReadBasic.All is missing). This worked and I was trying to identify what I had in my configuration differently. And it was "Authorized client applications" list - I had Frontend app configured in my backend. "Authorized client applications" list in "Expose an API" of Backend must be empty, otherwise consent is not displayed at all. Accepting answer, thanks.